# Flutter "Unable to load asset" error, although everything looks good

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image, pubspec

So I got the "Unable to load asset" error on an image, although everything looks good to me, tried running `flutter clean` in the terminal but it didn't fix the issue. Any suggestions?

PS: adding the file extension in the widget doesn't solve the issue

[image: This is the error]

[image: Project Tree]

[image: This is the pubspec]

[image: This is the code]

Answer (score 0):

Use full path, **.png** is missing

```
AssetImage('assets/images/image.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but please read the full body of the question again.

Comment: can you kill app and run the application again, try with force reload

Comment: after stopping and running the app again a few times it was fixed, very weird, thanks anyway!

Comment: That because, hot restart doesn't reload images, you have hot reload or try with killing application

Answer (score 0):

In the image name, you forgot the .png . So do this

```
AssetImage("assets/images/White-E-Journal.png")
```

instead of

```
AssetImage("assets/images/White-E-Journal")
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but please read the full body of the question again.